# Query age in prometheus alertmanager rule to be exported in grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm trying to create a table with all the active issues from Alertmanager in Grafana.
I can't really find a good guide on Alertmanager Queries, I've been trying to add a new column in the table with the AGE of the alert (1m, 1h, etc).
I found something on stackoverflow that points me in the right direction but I don't really understand the query.

```
  for: 5m
  expr: ...
  annotations:
    timestamp: >
      time: {{ with query "time()" }}{{ . | first | value | humanizeTimestamp }}{{ end }}
```

Can I find somewhere an in-depth documentation for the Alertmanager queries?

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is [Prometheus Templating Language](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/template_examples/#display-one-value), based on [Golang templating language](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Examples)

Another example:

```
{{ with query "some_metric{instance='someinstance'}" }}
  {{ . | first | value | humanize }}
{{ end }}
```

For specific alertmanager templating, look at [this page](https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/notifications/#alert)

Comment: thanks but how do I find out the prometheus data that I have to query. I need the duration of the alert so I need to query the time when the alert was fired by alertmanager.
time() seems to query for the current timestamp

Comment: @cduma See my update. `StartsAt` is probably what you want to play with.